# Mouse and keyboard suddenly stop responding while playing a video on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics

This is not happening just after opening a video. I experience this issue in situations like,

- trying to maximizing/minimizing the video
- trying to run some script on command line

I checked the system log, but no entries there for the time that this problem was occurred. But there was some entries like,

```
nouveau 0000:00:10.0: bus: MMIO write of 020e0001 FAULT at 00b030
nouveau 0000:00:10.0: bus: MMIO write of 020e0001 FAULT at 00b030
```

I use,

- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- nouveau graphic driver
- C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i] (on-board VGA)

Comment: Try using NVIDIA drivers 304.137 instead. No idea how they can be installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: NVIDIA drivers already showed under additional drivers and as you said I change it from Nouveau to NVIDIA(version 304.135). But then even videos did not open. But sometimes it may be some other issue. So I will try to install NVIDIA drivers correctly.